# No module name pyspark error

Tags: python, pyspark

This is the exact code from a tutorial I'm following. My classmate didn't get this error with the same code:

```
ImportError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-c6e1bed850ab> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyspark import SparkContext
      2 sc = SparkContext('local', 'Exam_3')
      3 
      4 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
      5 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

This is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local', 'Exam_3')
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext    
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data = sc.textFile("exam3")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: [float(x) for x in line.split(',')])
retail = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parsedData, 
     ['category_name','product_id', 'product_name', 'product_price'])
retail.registerTempTable("exam3")
print parsedData.take(3)
```

Comment: Do you have the pyspark module installed?  http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: it should be. I'm running it from a virtual machine that the whole class is using. Only one other person had the same issue and it was because they didn't load the profile but in my case I did load the profile.

Answer (score 34):

You don't have `pyspark` installed in a place available to the python installation you're using. To confirm this, on your command line terminal, with your `virtualenv` activated, enter your REPL (`python`) and type `import pyspark`:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Dec  3 2015, 09:58:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

If you see the `No module name 'pyspark'` ImportError you need to install that library. Quit the REPL and type:

```
pip install pyspark
```

Then re-enter the repl to confirm it works:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Dec  3 2015, 09:58:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
>>>
```

As a note, it is critical your virtual environment is activated. When in the directory of your virtual environment:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

These instructions are for a unix-based machine, and will vary for Windows.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You're right. My professor had to re-install it.

Comment: Do we still need to type pip install pyspark, even though we have set it up via command prompt as such https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633549/pyspark-anaconda3-envs-xgboost-python-exe-was-unexpected-at-this-time/52635160#52635160 ?

Answer (score 20):

Just use:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
```

If you don't have findspark module install it with:

```
python -m pip install findspark
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.x.x don't know which one back than I was using exactly...

Answer (score 13):

You can use `findspark` to make spark accessible at run time.  Typically `findspark` will find the directory where you have installed spark, but if it is installed in a non-standard location, you can point it to the correct directory. Once you have installed `findspark`, if spark is installed at `/path/to/spark_home` just put

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/path/to/spark_home')
```

at the very top of your script/notebook and you should now be able to access the pyspark module.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest solution that is worked for me FOR **MAC** users only. I've installed pyspark through `pip install pyspark`. But, it didn't work when I execute `pyspark` in terminal or even in python import pyspark. I checked that pyspark already installed in my laptop.

At the end, I found the solution. You just need to add into the bash profile file.

Follow steps:

1) Type the following in a terminal window to go to your home folder.

`cd ~`

2) Then the following to create a .bash_profile. (You may skip if it already exists.)

`touch .bash_profile`

3) `open -e .bash_profile`

Then **add** the following variables.

```
export SPARK_VERSION=`ls /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/ | sort | tail -1`
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/$SPARK_VERSION/libexec"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

**YOU NEED TO CHANGE py4j-x.x.x-src.zip version number in LAST LINE**

4) Once all these variables are assigned, save and close .bash_profile. Then the type following command to reload the file.

`. .bash_profile`

Comment: For the first command, since I'm using python 3.x. I used instead `pip3 install pyspark`

Answer (score 1):

I meet this error after

```
conda install pyspark
```

then i

```
pip install pyspark
```

this install py4j automatically, then comes right

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first to install pyspark using **conda** :

```
conda install pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

import findspark
findspark.init()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named 'findspark'

**$ pip install findspark**

it will work

Answer (score 0):

my solution to this problem was to

- open up a brand new .ipynb on local machine by:

> ```
> $jupyter-lab
> ```

- next in the very first cell running this:

> $pip install pyspark

my output is:

```
Collecting pyspark   
  Using cached pyspark-3.2.0.tar.gz (281.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done 
Collecting py4j==0.10.9.2
  Using cached py4j-0.10.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (198 kB) 
Building wheels for collected packages: pyspark   
  Building wheel for pyspark (setup.py) ... done   
  Created wheel for pyspark: filename=pyspark-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=281805913 sha256=26e539058858454dbbb48158111968d67e663c7b53e64c4fd91e38d92ac1cd80 
  Stored in directory: /Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/2f/f8/95/2ad14a4614b4a9f645ee928fbbd057b1b254c67adb494c9a58 
Successfully built pyspark Installing collected packages: py4j, pyspark 
Successfully installed py4j-0.10.9.2 pyspark-3.2.0 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

- then import pyspark:

> $import pyspark

You may as well want to try running the pip command directly in the lab env.