# Pyspark: \Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\python.exe] was unexpected at this time

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I am trying to install Pyspark in Windows.

I applied setx to the following:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON "C:\Users\Sade D\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\Scripts\jupyter.exe"
HADOOP_HOME "C:\spark\hadoop"
JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS "notebook"
PYSPARK_PYTHON "C:\Users\Sade D\Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\python.exe"
SCALA_HOME "C:\spark\scala"
SPARK_HOME "C:\spark\spark"
JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"
```

In system variables in path I have attached the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
C:\spark\spark\bin
C:\spark\spark\python
C:\spark\spark\python\lib
C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark
C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql
C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\mllib
C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\ml
C:\spark\spark\python\lib
C:\spark\scala\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
```

I followed the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQErwxRTiW0). I am running Anaconda python version 3.6, [Apache Spark 2.3.2](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), [Scala 2.12.7 msi](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/), and [hadoop 2.7](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1).

I verified anaconda, python and java versions on cmd line. This ensures that it is link correctly to the part. When I run pyspark in cmd prompt, I get an error \Anaconda3\envs\xgboost\python.exe] was unexpected at this time and the system can not find path specified. To verify the paths list I copy it an paste in the address to confirm it goes to the correct folder. In some blogs the solution suggested to add in the additional paths in system variables which I have done, hence there is more paths listed than what shown in the tutorial. How can this error be rectified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having issues with spaces in folder names, in particular the space in `C:\Users\Sade D`, where you appear to have installed Anaconda.

Try uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalling it in a folder without any spaces.  The video uses `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` (you can see this at 5:34): try installing into that folder instead of `C:\Users\Sade D`.

Comment: I created an extra account on my windows and added it as the admin account and by doing so I changed my account to a normal system account and followed this link

https://www.groovypost.com/news/microsoft-releases-cumulative-update-kb4058258-build-16299-214/

Now the issues have been removed and reinstalled my Anaconda and add-ons.

Comment: @Sade were you  able to resolve the issue. I am also facing similar issue and looking for a solution

Comment: @DevarshiMandal - yes i did, kindly refer to my comment above.