# "] was unexpected at this time". Error while launching pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have installed pyspark 3.2 on my system along with jdk 1.8.0
I am trying to launch pyspark from my command prompt, when I receive the following error

```
] was unexpected at this time
```

[image: CMD prompt error screenshot]

Based on some research I came to know that this may have to do with my environment variables, PFB the relevant variables

```
JRE_HOME:C:\Java\jre1.8.0_251
JAVA_HOME:C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_251
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON:C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
PYSPARK_PYTHON:C:\Users\jaisre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
SPARK_HOME:C:\spark\spark3.2.0binhadoop3.2
```

I have also added the below entries to Path variable

```
C:\Users\jaisre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Users\jaisre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Script
C:\spark\spark3.2.0binhadoop3.2\bin
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
```

Kindly suggest how to resolve this issue

Comment: Did you accidentally forget to post any details? You need a [mre] at least.

Comment: Your environment variables don't need spaces if your Spark installation path itself does have them

Comment: @RandomDavis I have added more relevant information, Thanks!

Comment: It seems like some path must contain unexpected spaces. All the similar issues I've found, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635160/6273251), were resolved by removing spaces from a path. It doesn't look like you have spaces in the environment variables you shared, so I'm not sure what could be causing the issue but I'm no expert.

Comment: No expert in Spark, but is `C:\spark\spark3.2.0binhadoop3.2\bin` correct? My gut feeling expects something like `C:\spark\spark3.2.0\bin\hadoop3.2\bin`, but on the other hand, maybe this is just some odd folder name.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I had renamed the folder so that that t doens't cause any issues in the sytem variables

Answer (score 0):

Except of Java_Home,Spark_Home and Hadoop_Home environmental variables, there is no need to set rest of the variables. If you look the various scripts (ex:pyspark) at your SPARK_HOME\bin location, the logic is already written to figure out rest of the variable path if not set. Cross verify if your set path match what is expected by these scripts.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvRAU.png)