# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'** while my Pyspark is installed on the machine

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark

I Tried to run ***jupyter notebook*** on my terminal and then I've run the code below but got this error telling that pyspark is not existant in my machine.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()
```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'** while my Pyspark is installed on the machine.

Could you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: 99% of these is due to package was installed with *different* python version.

Comment: Could you help me? @rasjani maybe .bashrc was not good because when I tried to run pyspark from my terminal everything goes well

Comment: @pecar try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302314/no-module-name-pyspark-error

Comment: Hello @AbdennacerLachiheb thank you but I don't find the directory Cellar in my machine . I found /opt/homebrew/bin/pyspark, should I put it in the SPARK_HOME?